Why is SQL in React Server Components an Anti-pattern?
The following code has been a controversial pattern for a while. Some say "what's wrong with it", and others say "you should never do this".
// https://github.com/rauchg/how-is-this-not-illegal/blob/main/app/page.js
import { sql } from "@vercel/postgres";
import { headers } from "next/headers";
import { PokemonList, Pokemon } from "./components";

export default async function Home() {
  headers();
  const { rows } = await sql`SELECT * FROM pokemon ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 12`; //  HERE

  return (
    <PokemonList>
      {rows.map((p) => (
        <Pokemon key={p.id} id={p.id} name={p.name} />
      ))}
    </PokemonList>
  );
}

I understand that

SQL queries shouldn't be ran on client side
SQL should be sanitized before running to prevent injection

Vercel team did some effort to solve this issues with the @vercel/postgres library.
Given these,

Is running SQL queries on React Server an anti-pattern?
What is a recommended way of fetching datas in React Server Components context (if you want to refrain from building the full backend server)?

